# JButton and JLabel next to each other

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I want to have a `JLabel` and a `JButton` next to each other, in the next row an other `Jlaben` and in the next row a `JButton` that is in the center.

The `leftPanel` is 350 wide.

The first `JButton` has an `ImageIcon` and that should be in the right top corner, that image is 25x25.

This code returns a panel to get then shown

```
JPanel leftPanel = JPanel();

leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

JLabel userLabel = new JLabel();
userLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 25));
userLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(170, 25));
leftPanel.add(userLabel);

// class that creats a JButton with an ImageIcon and removes border
JButton updateButton = DefaultLayouts.imageButton(new ImageIcon("src/ressources/images/icons/update.png"));
updateButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 25));
updateButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(170, 25));

leftPanel.add(updateButton);

timeStampLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 25));
timeStampLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(350, 25));
leftPanel.add(timeStampLabel);

unlockButton = DefaultLayouts.imageButton(new ImageIcon("src/ressources/images/icons/unlock.png"));
unlockButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 25));
unlockButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(350, 25));

leftPanel.add(unlockButton);

panel.add(leftPanel();
```

Now it's just in the center and I don't know what to do with the blue button. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kknFI.jpg)

Updated Code:

```
JPanel panel = DefaultLayouts.panel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

JPanel leftPanel = DefaultLayouts.marginPanel(0, 10, 0, 10);
leftPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;

gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
leftPanel.add(userLabel, gridBagConstraints);

JButton updateButton = DefaultLayouts.imageButton(new ImageIcon("src/ressources/images/icons/update.png"));
gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
leftPanel.add(updateButton, gridBagConstraints);

gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
leftPanel.add(timeStampLabel, gridBagConstraints);

unlockButton = DefaultLayouts.imageButton(new ImageIcon("src/ressources/images/icons/unlock.png"));
gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 3;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
leftPanel.add(unlockButton, gridBagConstraints);

panel.add(leftPanel);
```

Comment: Can you please add images with what do you have and what do you want?

Comment: Sorry for bad quality. I want the blue box next to the green one and the image should be in the top right corner. The color are removed in the code above. Also the `leftPanel` has a margin that can be ignored. [image](http://i.imgur.com/GPbSe3X.jpg)

Comment: Take a look in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Let me know if you understand the explanation.

Comment: I'll look in to it and try to it.

Comment: I've updated my code but it still doesn't do what i want, it doesnn't help to set a preferred and max size. @josivan

Comment: Actually, isn't mandatory to define the preferred size.Try to define de size in panel that have the layout.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height. 3) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 4) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FlowLayout or GridLayout.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//or panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));

panel.add(new JLabel("Label"));
panel.add(new JButton("Click"));
```